# Is OpenCV 2.0 optimized for AMD processors?

Tags: opencv, x86-64, amd-processor

I know that in the past OpenCV was based on IPP and was optimized only for Intel CPUs. Is this still the case with OpenCV 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

History says that OpenCV was originally developed by Intel.

If you check [OpenCV faq](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/faq), they'll say:

*OpenCV itself is open source and written in quite portable C/C++, it runs on other processors already and should be fairly easy to port (for example, there are already some CUDA optimizations on NVidia. On the other hand, OpenCV can sometimes run much faster on Intel processors (and sometimes AMD) because it can take advantage of SSE optimizations. OpenCV can be compiled statically with IPP libraries from Intel also which can speed up some function.*

I have used it on other processors and different OS and I've always been very happy, including for video processing applications.