# Running OpenCV on an AMD processor

Tags: opencv

First off: there is a similar question but it is *ten years old*. Obviously hardware changes in that time span ;)  [Is OpenCV 2.0 optimized for AMD processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366660/is-opencv-2-0-optimized-for-amd-processors).

My intention is to nuke the `windoze 10` on an AMD machine with `AMD Ryzen 7 R7-3750H` cpu and install `ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS`.  Will `opencv` work -i.e. will it compile and run?  What would I expect in terms of performance vs a bit older `core i7` ?

Comment: Do you mean't AMD (ATI) GPU - then yes, since OpenCV using [OpenCL](https://opencv.org/opencl/)  i.e. no NVidea only CUDA based GPGPU acceleration, and your video card can be used. Don't forget to install proprietary GPU drivers to get GPU accelerated OpenCL support.

Comment: No I am looking at a machine having an `nVidia` GPU. But I want a machine capable to run `opencv` on both `cpu` and `gpu` thus the AMD cpu needs to at least work.